# How to select all records from table apart from the last 100

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a database that stores customers records and I would like to set up a cron job to overwrite these records periodically. I would like to say Select * from ORDERS where ORDER_ID is not in the top 100 of the list. Each row has its own order_id with the latest order_id being the latest order. I need to keep the latest 100 order ids in case of some problems. Thank you for your time.

Comment: What do you mean by 'overwrite'?

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from Orders
where OrderID not in (
    select OrderID 
    from Orders 
    order by OrderID desc 
    limit 100)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. I appear to be receiving the error message: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in...

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from order-table WHERE order_id NOT IN (
    SELECT order_id
    from order-table
    ORDER BY order_id desc 
    LIMIT 100)");
 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

 echo $row['order_id'];

 echo "<br />";
}

Comment: It would appear to be the limit 100 that is causing the problem as it is not allowed in a subquery? Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

You can left join a rowset of 100 last order_id's - this will result in all but 100 last having NULL in the left joined set.

```
SELECT o.* from `order-table` o
LEFT JOIN
  ( SELECT order_id FROM `order-table` ORDER BY order_id DESC LIMIT 100 ) o100
ON o.order_id = o100.order_id
WHERE o100.order_id IS NULL
```