# Select all results from mysql table apart from the latest 100

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to select all records from table apart from the last 100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116036/how-to-select-all-records-from-table-apart-from-the-last-100)

I wish to run a cron job wiping out some customer information. I have a table which stores the customers information and I am just testing SQL queries to make sure it will work. I am having problems with this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from order-table WHERE order_id NOT IN (
SELECT order_id
from order-table
ORDER BY order_id desc) LIMIT 50");


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo $row['order_id'];

echo "<br />";
}
```

The problem is that I receive an error: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

If I try the query directly in SQL I get a message that LIMIT is not supported in a subquery, so I was hoping someone might be able to help me achieve this in another way? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have `LIMIT` inside an `IN` or `NOT IN` subquery. But you can in a subquery in the `FROM` or `WHERE` clause. The trick is to have the subquery return 1 row only and then use `<` or `<=` to compare that value.

This will show all rows except the (ordered by `order_id`) last 50:

```
SELECT ot.* 
FROM order-table AS ot 
  JOIN 
    ( SELECT order_id
      FROM order-table
      ORDER BY order_id DESC
        LIMIT 1 OFFSET 50
    ) AS lim
    ON ot.order_id <= lim.order_id ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Retrieve 50 rows, skipping the top 100:

```
SELECT * FROM order_table ORDER BY order_id DESC LIMIT 100,50
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure this is what I am after. If I try this:
    
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from order-table WHERE order_id NOT IN (
   SELECT * FROM order-table ORDER BY order_id DESC LIMIT 0,100)");
 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

 echo $row['order_id'];

 echo "<br />";
}


I get the same error message

Comment: No, this is the whole query. It doesn't go into a subquery. Just copy exactly what I wrote into your `mysql_query()`. You don't need a complex query to skip the top or bottom X rows... LIMIT with an offset does that.

Comment: Hello, I have entered the code and it gives me the top 50 order_ids but I need to say Select all rows apart from these ones, in order to wipe all customer info which is 50 orders old. If I use your code after the NOT IN, I still receive the same error as the Limit is not allowed in a subquery?

Comment: Then you're asking the wrong question. Just `SELECT order_id FROM order_table ORDER BY order_id DESC LIMIT 50,1` to get the 51st order id, then `DELETE FROM order_table WHERE order_id < thatnumber`.

Comment: I see Dan, I hadn't thought of that way of doing it. The only thing I'm having a problem with now is simply referencing thatnumber ---

I thought this would work but I get the boolean error again:

    `$result = mysql_query("SELECT order_id FROM jos_vm_order_payment ORDER BY order_id DESC LIMIT 50,1");
$resultb = mysql_query("SELECT order_id FROM jos_vm_order_payment WHERE order_id < $result");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultb)){

 echo $row['order_id'];

 echo "<br />";
}`

Comment: `$result` is a pointer to the result resource returned by `mysql_query`, not a number. You need to fetch the row out of the resource with `mysql_fetch_array`, as you already know how to do, and read the `order_id` index in that array.